# WP JSON API with OAuth - Proper channel

Tags: wordpress, oauth, wp-api

I have Have [WP API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/)  and [OAuth1](https://github.com/WP-API/OAuth1) plugins installed for my python frontend to access posts in wordpress. With CLI `wp oauth add` I have generated secret and key also. But am stuck on how to proceed further. I can check api responses via chrome advanced REST client.

I get proper JSON responses from requests like GET `http://mylocal.site/wp-json/posts`

But I want to add authentication. Read numerous docs from api and oauth...but nowhere a proper work flow. Please shed some light who have worked with these already.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working following the base https://github.com/WP-API/OAuth1